# Visual Studio 2012 merge of VB6 code automagically makes bad changes to code

Tags: vb6, visual-studio-2012, merge

I am currently trying to merge some changes done in VB6 code with Visual Studio 2012.

The merge tool automagically removes "Set" in front of assignments, "Variant" is changed to "Object" and calls to "Sub" methods automagically gets parenthesises "()" inserted around the arguments. This makes VB6 unable to compile the result if i check it in!

It seems that only rows that is changed or in conflict is affected.

A merge tool should not employ magical things like that! As it is now i can't use VS2012 to merge changes we make in our old VB6 code.

Please, is there any way to dissable this functionality?

Thanks!

Comment: @Deanna : Turning off all autoformatting options in VB.Net seems to work. Since I'm not using VB.Net this is OK for me.
Thanks!

Comment: I had this happen too. messed up a bunch of code!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The code reformatting is being down implicitly by the IDE as it thinks it is VB.Net code where those changes are required.

You can either turn off the auto formatting options for VB.Net code, or use another merge tool like [WinMerge](http://winmerge.org/).